# In-page search using contains() to show/hide div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

I am trying to add a search functionality to my FAQ page and am absolutely stuck.

What I want is a text box where the user inputs a keyword(or words), that runs a jquery for the keyword and sets display:block for all the relevant answers.

What I have so far is this:

```
    <form name="searchBox">
       Keyword(s): <input type="text" name="keyword" />
       <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="searchFunction()" />
    </form>
    <div class="searchable" style="display:none">
       This is the first software question and answer.</div>
    <div class="searchable" style="display:none">
       This is the first hardware question and answer.</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function searchFunction() {
          var searchTerm = document.searchBox.keyword.value;
          $(" :contains('"+searchTerm+"')").addStyle("display:block"); }
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `searchTerm`?

Comment: Please elaborate on why this isn't working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
function searchFunction() {
          var searchTerm = document.searchBox.keyword.value;
          $(".searchable").each(function(){
              $(this).(":contains('"+searchTerm+"')").show(); 
           });

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
function searchFunction() {
    $(".searchable")
        .hide()
        .filter(":contains('" + $("input[name='keyword']").val() + "')")
        .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change .addStyle("display:block") to .show()