# How to use Rails Each Array and In-page search to show/hide div content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to set up a simple search bar to show/hide content in my rails app. Specifically, trying to allow someone to search for a specific user via username in my chatroom which are being shown using a Rails each array. I looked at these two questions for guidance but still didn't get it to work - [In-page search using contains() to show/hide div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709718/in-page-search-using-contains-to-show-hide-div-content) and [Dynamical search-function to show/hide divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353009/dynamical-search-function-to-show-hide-divs). Whenever, I type a user's name though in my search box nothing appears. I have listed my code below and any help on this matter would be amazing. Thank you so much!

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <form name="searchBox">
   Search for a User: <input type="text" name="keyword" />
   <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="searchFunction()" />
</form>
<% (User.all - [current_user]).each do |user| %>
<div class="box2" style="display:none" id="searchable">
            <%= image_tag user.background, height: 95, width: 165, class: "css-style4"   %>             
            <strong><%= link_to user.username, direct_message_path(user.id), data: {behavior: "chatroom-link", chatroom_id: Chatroom.direct_message_for_users([current_user, user]).id} %></strong>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**chatroomsearch.js**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load',function(){
function searchFunction() {
$("#searchable")
    .hide()
    .filter(":contains('" + $("input[name='keyword']").val() + "')")
    .show();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your searchFunction function in $(document).ready() function?

Comment: @SarmadSabih I did using $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){ which i believe is the replacement for document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
<div class="box2" style="display:none" id="searchable">
```

The IDs must be unique. Hence, remove them and use them as a class like in:

```
<div class="box2 searchable" style="display:none">
```

In this way you need to change the selector:

```
$("#searchable")
```

to:

```
$(".searchable")
```

The snippet:

```js
function searchFunction() {
    $(".searchable")
            .hide()
            .filter(":contains('" + $("input[name='keyword']").val() + "')")
            .show();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-4">
    <form name="searchBox">
        Search for a User: <input type="text" name="keyword"/>
        <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="searchFunction()"/>
    </form>
    <div class="box2 searchable" style="display:none">
        <strong><a href='/direct_messages/1' data-behavior="chatroom-link"
                   data-chatroom_id="Chatroom.direct_message_for_users([current‌​_user, user]).id">Rodrigo1 Williams</a></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="box2 searchable" style="display:none">
        <strong><a href='/direct_messages/1' data-behavior="chatroom-link"
                   data-chatroom_id="Chatroom.direct_message_for_users([current‌​_user, user]).id">Rodrigo2 Williams</a></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, your explanation is awesome but it still doesn't work for me. I have a feeling it might be due to this line from rails `<strong><%= link_to user.username, direct_message_path(user.id), data: {behavior: "chatroom-link", chatroom_id: Chatroom.direct_message_for_users([current_user, user]).id} %></strong>` Bc when i type a user's name it doesn't call it.

Comment: Trying to figure it out, never done that a ruby line to html conversion before. Reading documentation right now.

Comment: i think that rails line in html looks like this based on the documentation examples: `<a href='/direct_messages/1' data-behavior="chatroom-link" data-chatroom_id="Chatroom.direct_message_for_users([current_user, user]).id">Rodrigo Williams</a>`

Comment: @Omar Snippet updated using your anchor. Now if you type **Rodrigo** and click the button it should work. Let me know how can I help you.

Comment: Thank you so much @gaetanoM have an awesome day champ!